# navigation drawer does not fit in the activity

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I want to use a `NavigationDrawer` but it does not fit in the `Activity`. I am using `ActionBarTab` and `Fragment` in the `Activity`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.basket.MainActivity" >
  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1" />

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ListView         
        android:padding="0dp" 
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are new with this I recommend you follow [these](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) instructions to create a new Navigation Drawer

If you follow the recommendations you will see that here it is doing inversely that the way you're doing

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Design

```
1. android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
  1.1 FrameLayout (Main content view)
  1.2 ListView (Navigation drawer)
```

With the image below you can understand better how it works

[image]

But if you want to continue doing like you show in your question you have to delete  paddings attribute in your DrawerLayout like the example below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.basket.MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
        <ListView
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of these lines in your xml:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

They are adding an inner padding which prevents your drawer from reaching the edges of the fragment. Removing these lines will likely cause your other views to extend to the edges as well, so you'll have to adjust your layout as necessary.